# Building QT with QWT: qwt_plot.h not found

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

I'm trying to build a program using QWT with QT Creator. The plugin works fine and if I add a plot to the main window form, the file qwt_plot.h is automatically included in the header file belonging to the form. However, when I try to compile the project, qwt_plot.h is not found.

In my project file, the path to the qwt headers is included:

```
INCLUDEPATH += D:/qwt/Qwt-6.1.2/include/
```

This path is correct, and if I replace the #include "qwt_plot.h" directive by

```
#include "D:/qwt/Qwt-6.1.2/include/qwt_plot.h"
```

the file is found. If I include "qwt_plot.h" in the main file, it is found too, but without having to use the full path.

Why is qwt_plot.h not found in my ui_...h file belonging to the main window form?

Comment: did you run `qmake` after the change in `INCLUDEPATH` ?

Comment: @Zaiborg Yes and no. I did not explicitely run it. But running it manually solved the problem. Thanks!

I do not understand why I have to run qmake manually in this situation. It is called anyway when I build my project if the configuration changed. I also see the compile output line which tells me qmake has not been run, because the configuration did not change. (Which is now correct)